# Python Tkinter window.mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have copied the following code to experiment with animations using Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas.pack()
x0 = 10
y0 = 50
x1 = 60
y1 = 100
i = 0
deltax = 2
deltay = 3
which = canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill="red", tag='redBall')
while True:
    canvas.move('redBall', deltax, deltay)
    canvas.after(20)
    canvas.update()
    if x1 >= 400:
        deltax = -2
    if x0 < 0:
        deltax = 2
    if y1 > 300:
        deltay = -3
    if y0 < 0:
        deltay = 3
    x0 += deltax
    x1 += deltax
    y0 += deltay
    y1 += deltay
window.mainloop()
```

This works fine, but what I have noticed is that it seems to work the same with and without the line `window.mainloop()`. Furthermore, this line seemingly would never be called, because the prevailing `while` loop never breaks. However, I have seen this example code many times, so it seems that `window.mainloop()` does perform something important. What is that thing??

Comment: The code never get to `window.mainloop()` since there is an infinite `while True:` loop above it.  Typically you would use `mainloop()` to initiate the Tkinter event handler, however in this `canvas.update()` is causing the window to be shown and updated throughout the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`window.mainloop()` does not allow python interpreter to execute codes after that line until the the application is closed. For example you can add some print statements after the `window.mainloop()` you will find that python prints them after you close you app.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
#your code here
root.mainloop()
#now print
print 'Mainloop over'
```

In this way the program loops within the mainloop allowing buttons and other widgets to perform multiple times, else program would not execute after first execution.